# django Getting unwatched items

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

```
class Photo(models.Model):
    ...    
    viewsT = models.ManyToManyField('PhotoViewT', symmetrical=False)
    ...

class PhotoViewT(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    creationdate = models.DateTimeField()
```

I store photos' information in "Photo" table and information about views in "PhotoViewT" table  (Here is "user" who watched photo and "creationdate" when he watched it). On "photo" I have m2m field to views, where I add information about all views.

My task is to get photos, those haven't been already watched by current defined user. I have no clue how to craft this query.

Something like

```
Photo.objects.filter(viewsT__user__doesnt_contain=targetUser)
```

Expression above hardly does work. Any solutions? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ref [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships). Try

```
Photo.objects.exclude(viewsT__user=targetUser)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Photo.photoviewtset.all()` will fetch you all `PhotoViewT` instances associated with that `Photo`.

`Photo.photoviewtset.filter(user=<your_current_user)` will fetch you all `PhotoViewT` instances associated with that `Photo` filtered by your `current_user`.

Note: You do not need the ManyToManyField in the `Photo` model for this

Answer (score 0):

```
 Photo.objects.exclude(viewsT__in=PhotoViewT.objects.filter(user=request.user))

 OR

 Photo.objects.filter(~Q(viewsT__in=PhotoViewT.objects.filter(user=request.user)))
```